# Neo4j in distributed mode - is it possible?

Tags: neo4j

I can't find any answer in the Internet to this question.
Is it possible to launch Neo4j in distributed mode to gain better performance? Why/Why not?

Comment: Distribute data into many machines

Comment: As far as performance is concerned, if you have a query that's not performing well, maybe create a separate question for it. Query tuning should be the first step when you run into performance issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neo4j Enterprise has clustering but it is for high availability.

It does not shard like TigerGraph for example.

Each instance (node) in the cluster has a replication of the full data set.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you're asking about database sharding. The short answer is no, this feature isn't supported.

Neo4j has two primary clustering modes, the older [HA (highly available) clustering](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/high-availability/#cluster-installation), and the newer [Causal Clustering](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/causal-clustering/), and both require Enterprise Edition. In both cases all nodes participating in the cluster must contain the entire graph.

For now I'll stick with causal clustering, as that's where feature development is continuing.

As far as read scaling, that can be scaled horizontally by adding read replicas to the cluster. The bolt+routing protocol ensures that explicit read transactions using the driver are routed to either one of the followers or a read replica, and take load into account to some degree.

For write scaling, that is vertical only, as only one node at a time (the elected leader) is allowed to write, so ensuring that all core nodes (the nodes in the cluster that can potentially be elected leader) have adequate RAM, disk space, and SSDs is critical.

EDIT:

[Neo4j Fabric](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.0/fabric/introduction/) was introduced in January 2020 with the release of Neo4j 4.0. This allows sharding of data across multiple shards (databases or clusters, and they don't need any additional configuration to be used as a shard), and ways to query over these multiple shards and work with the results.

Comment: So on each machine there is entire graph? So cypher query is executed exactly on one machine?

Comment: Yes. For causal cluster, if it's an explicit write query it will execute on the leader, otherwise it will be routed to either a follower or a read replica.

Comment: So what benefit? Throughput?

Comment: What about this piece of documentation here? https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-fabric-sharding/ - they explain how to split data by user etc. Is it not true?

Comment: @kirhgoff Fabric was only introduced in January 2020 with Neo4j 4.0, so it didn't exist at the time the question was asked and answered. With fabric queries can be distributed across shards, each shard will run the query in parallel and return data that you can continue to work with. Note that while this will allow horizontal scaling and some parallel execution, it does introduce network I/O if these are remote shards.

Answer (score 0):

The Enterprise Edition of neo4j supports [Highly Available Clusters](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/high-availability/#cluster-installation). Additional further documentation is [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/).

Comment: Could you explain how data are distributed (determining nodes to machines)

Comment: The documentation at the links in my answer explain that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only in enterprise mode. It has a master slave architecture; the master serves write requests and the slaves are responsible for read traffic. Refer to [Understanding Neo4j Scalability](http://na-sjl.marketo.com/rs/neotechnology/images/Understanding%20Neo4j%20Scalability(2).pdf) for details.

However, if the enterprise version is not in your budget for some reason (like it wasn't in ours) we set up a multi master community edition cluster and kept the masters in sync using two phased commits.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended you could try [GraphScope](https://github.com/alibaba/GraphScope), a one-stop graph processing platform, which is capable of processing extra large scale graphs and could be easily scaled to multiple nodes.

It's API is simple, for example

```py
Here's the code

import graphscope
sess = graphscope.session(num_workers=4)
graph = sess.g()
graph = graph.add_edges('/path/to/dataset')

interactive = sess.interactive(graph)
print(interactive.cypher('...'))
sess.close()
```

You could refer to [this article](https://blog.graphscope.io/how-to-run-graphscope-on-kubernetes-cluster-1c8359e29d2d) to learn how to deploy graphscope, and [this article](https://blog.graphscope.io/how-to-deploy-graphscope-by-helm-on-kubernetes-999a791918aa) to learn how to deploy by helm.